# Word wrap in Sphinx autosummary-generated table

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, word-wrap

I use Sphinx to generate the docs for my project, with the extension `autosummary`. It generates a table with the names of my modules and their summary.

Here is an image of the result :

[image: Table generated by autosummary]

However, the lines are too long and we have to use the slider to read the whole description.

**I would like to wrap the description text, to get rid of the slider bar**. I have searched everywhere and found nothing.

I tried putting `| xxxx` or `<br /> xxxx` in my description but it did not work.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Override the CSS on the table with your own styles. Specifically `.wy-table-responsive table td, .wy-table-responsive table th { white-space: normal; }` should take care of most of the problems. Or use a theme that does not use scrolling tables in its styles.

Comment: @StevePiercy it worked, thank you very much ! Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted :)

Comment: done, and thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the CSS on the table with your own styles. Specifically:

```css
.wy-table-responsive table td,
.wy-table-responsive table th {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

should take care of most of the problems. Or use a theme that does not use scrolling tables in its styles.

Comment: @Kalanos this is the accepted answer for the given question. Please create a new question if this does not answer your new question, instead of adding comments.

Comment: This solution produces the OP's desired and intended result. How does your comment provide any efficacy?

Comment: Making aimless comments for an accepted answer does not help. If your comment actually improved the accepted answer, then it would be helpful.

Comment: Beware that forcing `white-space:normal` will defer the `width` of the columns to the table's `colgroup` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36121672/set-table-column-width-via-markdown